# How can I remove the button label my dataset without affecting my chart

Tags: javascript, json

I  want to eliminate a label of my operation, but when I do, it affects all my function.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("CountryChart");<br>
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {<br><br>
    type: 'bar',<br>
    data: {<br>
        labels: ["México", "Japon", "USA", "China", "Pakistan"],<br><br>
    datasets: [{<br>
        label: '# Of Votes',**--this label i want to eliminate--**<br>
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],<br>
        backgroundColor: [<br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following option: This should hide it without affecting anything.

```
 options: { legend: { display: false }}
```